How to reorder groups programmatically
I have setup a timeline to follow document versioning. Each group is a document, and each item is a version. Unstacked they line up nicely.

Something I'd like to do is to raise groups of related documents (for example, part of a project) to the top but while I know they can be moved manually, I can't make them move/reorder programmatically.
For example, in this screenshot I have selected several related documents part of the same release, but I'd like the groups with selected items to move them to the top so they're together:

I am sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out why. If it's animated it would be great but it would be enough just being able to reorder.
All items have an "order" property but right now it's the same as the ID (which is numeric)

I seem to have been barking at the wrong tree. There's no method to reorder but, instead, an order function or field must be set.
Canonical example is this assuming an "order" field per group:
relTimeline.setOptions({groupOrder: function(a, b) {return b.order - a.order;}})
I assume that to dynamically rise to the top an arbitrary amount of groups, I should be ordering by a field I can modify for this.
